# What is the job for oe_runmake in yocto?

Tags: yocto, openembedded, build-system

I want to know about the oe_runmake in yocto.

Comment: oe_runmake() is a simple function that calls `make` for the recipe in question. If you want a better answer, you probably need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

oe_runmake function is used to run make.

oe_runmake

- passes EXTRA_OEMAKE settings to make
- displays the make command
- checks for errors generated via the call.

In OE environment you should not call make directly rather use oe_runmake when you need to run make.

oe_runmake is one of many helper functions defined by the base class.
For a list of helper functions you can refer [OEManual](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_methods.html)

Comment: can i pass any extra variable to that oe_run make

Comment: @VadalasettiSivanageswararao, yes you can. You can do `EXTRA_OEMAKE_append = " '<your-list>'"`. E.g., please see this [iproute2](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/iproute2/iproute2_4.7.0.bb?h=morty#n13) recipe in yocto meta layer.

Comment: Thanks now I undestood something on EXTRA_OEMAKE.

Comment: Does that mean that by calling oe_runmake we can pass some other global flags other than those are defined in the work/package folder?

Comment: @VishnuNK 
Yes. For example, refer poky/meta/recipes-extended/lsof/lsof_4.89.bb 
    oe_runmake 'CC=${CC}' 'CFGL=${LDFLAGS} -L./lib -llsof' 'DEBUG=' 'INCL=${CFLAGS}'